# Delete ActiveMQ queue after stopping a Camel Route

Tags: java, spring, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have an issue on deleting an ActiveMQ queue because due to the error

```
Destination   still has an active subscription: queue://MyQueue
```

The reason is that there's a consumer attached to the queue, this is what I see from the ActiveMQ console, but the consumer should not be there and be active (IMHO, but having the issue I'm surely wrong), because :

T0 : queue MyQueue having messages and no consumer attached
T1 : a Spring TaskScheduler execute a code that create a Camel Route in charge to move messages in another queue with this code

```
....
//context is a CamelContext instance autowired
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        public void configure() {

            from(myQueueURI)
            .id(myQueueURI)
            .to(destinationQueueURI);                       
        }
```

T2 : on a specific fixed interval, another Spring TaskScheduler is in charge to query MyQueue in order to understand if it's empty, and in this case, try to remove the queue.

```
....
....
@Autowired
public CachingConnectionFactory localCachingConnectionFactory;
....
....
removeCamelRoutes(queueName, routeId);

private boolean removeCamelRoutes(String queueName, String routeId) throws JMSException{

        if (isQueueEmpty(queueName)){
            try {
                //context is a CamelContext instance autowired
                context.stopRoute(routeId);
                context.removeRoute(routeId);
                deleteQueue(queueName);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //logs 
                return false;
            }
        }
        ....
        ....
}

private boolean isQueueEmpty(String queueName) throws JMSException{
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = (ActiveMQConnectionFactory) localCachingConnectionFactory.getTargetConnectionFactory();
    ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) activeMQConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    ActiveMQQueue queue = (ActiveMQQueue) session.createQueue(queueName);
    QueueBrowser queueBrowser = session.createBrowser(queue);
    try {
        if (queueBrowser.getEnumeration().hasMoreElements()){
            queueBrowser.close();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    finally {
        if (queueBrowser != null) {
            queueBrowser.close();       
        }
        session.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}


private void deleteQueue(String queueName) throws Exception {

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = (ActiveMQConnectionFactory) localCachingConnectionFactory.getTargetConnectionFactory();
    ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) activeMQConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    ActiveMQQueue queue = (ActiveMQQueue) session.createQueue(queueName);

    try {
        //HERE is where the operation is failing
        connection.destroyDestination(queue);
    } 
    finally {
        session.close();
        connection.close();
    }

}
```

I ask for some hints on where I miss something about the still alive consumer, I was thinking about the consumer related to Camel Route but it should be closed automatically with the Route, it could be the consumer attached on querying the queue, but I should have closed correctly Session and Connection.

Camel version 2.15.1, ActiveMQ 5.9.0, Spring 4.1.3

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is the Camel route active? If so you need to stop that route so the route is not active and consuming from the JMS queue which prevents you from deleting the queue.

Comment: Hi Claus, yes the route is stopped by the instruction `context.stopRoute(routeId);` 
In the previous version of my code I also checked the boolean result of that 
operation before proceeding.
Thanks